# Amazon Alexa: Control TCP device from SmartHomeSkill lambda

Tags: node.js, sockets, alexa-skills-kit

I have a SmartHomeSkill created with the lambda template.

I have another lambda that is a plain skill function.

I'm using NodeJS for both. I connect through TCP directly to my local router using sockets in Node.

A plain Lambda using Sockets to connect: works!
A Skill Lambda using Sockets to connect: works!
A Skill Lambda calling another Lambda (from Step 1) using aws-sdk: works!
Using a SmartHomeSkill to call Sockets: does not work!
Using a SmartHomeSkill to call another Lambda: does not work!
I'm using the same IAM role for all. So because scenario 1 to 3 work, I assume my role is good. I'm using a custom policy for inter-lambda calls.

My SmartHomeSkill authenticates using AWS role and I get valid requests with token and everything.

Both, my inter-lambda and the TCP-device does not have any authentication capabilities.

The TCP-device is selfmade electronics. It works well with plain lambda and local software.

The only thing is: As soon as I switch to the SmartHomeSkill template nothing goes. However, the skill itself works. I can discover devices, and Alexas sends invoke requests without complaining. I'm logging a lot and all looks good up the point it goes outside. In both scenarios, using plai TCP socket or HTTP call to another lambda it does nothing, no error, no response.

Question: Is the SmartHomeSkill somehow limited using outbound connections. But if, how it connects to other devices, such as Phillips Hue?

--

This is my (perfectly working) inter-lambda that accepts HTTP payload and resends it using TCP:

```
var net = require('net');

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    console.log(`event=${event}`);
    var payload = event.payload;
    sendKnx(payload.ga, +payload.v);
    // TODO implement
    callback(null, 'Hello from Lambda');
};
// ---- outbound -----
function sendKnx(ga, v) {
  var noreply = true;
  var dir = "W";
  if (ga) {
    console.log('**** Incoming TCP request from Client');
    // make numerical ga from convient one
    var parts = ga.split('/');
    if (parts.length === 3) {
      var hi = +parts[0];
      var mi = +parts[1];
      var lo = +parts[2];
      var gnumerical = hi * 2048 + mi * 256 + lo;
      // each time we send a package we connect, send, and close in one step
      // This is EibPC
      console.log('**** Connect using ' + gnumerical);
      try {
        var client = new net.Socket();
        console.log('**** Socket created');
        client.connect(8888, 'this.is.my.cloud.server', function () {
          console.log(`**** Send Data ${gnumerical}=${v}`);
          client.write(`${dir}|${gnumerical}=${v}`);
          if (noreply){
            client.destroy();
            console.log('**** Socket destroyed');
          }
        });
        client.on('data', function (data) {
          console.log('Received TCP Response from EibPC: ' + data);
          client.destroy(); // kill client after server's response
        });
        client.on('close', function () {
          console.log('TCP Connection to EibPC closed');
        });
      } catch (Error) {
        console.error(`**** TCP sending failed: ${Error}`);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In my (perfectly working) regular skill lambda i'm going to to call this like this:

```
  function forwardLambdaCall(ga, v, context) {
   console.log('forwardLambdaCall');
   var payload = {
        "payload": {
            "ga": ga,
            "v": v
        }
   };
   lambda.invoke({
    FunctionName: 'KNXForwarder',
    InvocationType: 'RequestResponse',
    LogType:'Tail',
    Payload: JSON.stringify(payload) // pass params
   }, function(error, data) {
     console.log('Return forwardLambdaCall');
     if (error) {
      console.log('Error forwardLambdaCall' + error);
      context.done('error', error);
     } else {
      console.log('Success forwardLambdaCall' + data);
      context.succeed({});
   }
 });    
}
```

"KNXForwarder" is the name of the inter-lambda. Payload goes through and it works as expected. This is mainly for testing purpose, I wanted to assure that the forwarder is working.

If I use exactly the same call in my SmartHomeSkill, nothing happens.

> I have posted the name in Alexa forum: https://forums.developer.amazon.com/questions/58233/control-tcp-device-from-smarthomeskill-lambda.html. The duplication is on purpose because I found other questions evenly distributed here and there and and was unsure about the proper way to reach a broader developer audience.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, weird enough but maybe somebody can shed a little light on this.

First, problem solved.

I MUST send the TCP instruction before the connection from Alexa is being closed. It seems to me that when the inbound call ends with one of these any TCP traffic will end:

- context.succeed(...)
- context.fail(...)

So my new handler looks like this:

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    console.log(`event=${event}`);
    var result;
    if (event.header && event.header.namespace){
        switch (event.header.namespace) {

            case 'Alexa.ConnectedHome.Discovery':
                handleDiscovery(event, context);
                break;
            case 'Alexa.ConnectedHome.Control':
                result = handleControl(event, context);
                break;
            default:
                context.fail('Something went wrong');
                break;
        }
    }
    if (result){
        sendKnx(result.payload.ga, result.payload.v, () => context.succeed(result));
    }    
};
```

So the *handleControl* function does not end the communication but instead returns the values I want to extract. My TCP connection 'sendKnx' establishes the outbound communication and once that channel has been closed the Alexa connection get's its results. I'm using a callback (the third parameter) for that and it's working fine.

> It would be great to get some documentation about the call behavior. Especially, and that's why I'm complaining a bit, why the hell it behaves different if the trigger is a SmartHomeSkill compared to a regular Skill.